# Convert to Web Mercator With Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, gis, matplotlib-basemap

My program vertically stretches a Numpy array, representing a 180 by 360 map image, so it represents a Web Mercator map image.

I wrote a function (below) that does what I want - but it is crazy slow (takes like five minutes).  Is there a much faster and easier way to do this?  Maybe using Numpy `interpolate2d` or MatPlotLib?

```
def row2lat(row):
  return 180.0/math.pi*(2.0*math.atan(math.exp(row*math.pi/180.0))-math.pi/2.0)

def mercator(geodetic):
    geo = np.repeat(geodetic, 2, axis=0)
    merc = np.zeros_like(geo)
    side = geo[0].size
    for row in range(side):
        lat = row2lat(180 - ((row * 1.0)/side) * 360)
        g_row = (abs(90 - lat)/180)*side
        fraction = g_row-math.floor(g_row)
        for col in range(side):
            high_row = geo[math.floor(g_row)][col] * (fraction)
            low_row = geo[math.ceil(g_row)][col] * (1-fraction)
            merc[row][col] = high_row + low_row
    return merc
```

[image: Original]
[image: Final]

Comment: It's hard to understand without an example input (at least for me).
However the rule-of-thumb in making numpy fast is not to use for loop but to vectorize everything.

Comment: Apologies if the wording is confusing.  The task is pretty simple; to vertically pull a Numpy array so it stretches more at the top and bottom.

Comment: Do you just want to append zeros at the top and bottom of the array? Or resize it (like you resize a picture)?

Comment: The top and bottom pixels stretch around 3 times their height, more central pixels stretch less.  Like a picture printed on caramel.

Comment: I added images that show what the function does.

Comment: The brightness seems to be different. Is that intended, unwanted or doesn't matter?

Comment: That's just the PNG export being weird.  The underlying data should be about the same, just stretched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid the inner for loop and vectorize your functions. Numpy is highly optimized to run those things efficient. Your function would then read like

```
def mercator_faster(geodetic):
    geo = np.repeat(geodetic, 2, axis=0)
    merc = np.zeros_like(geo)
    side = geo[0].size
    for row in range(side):
        lat = row2lat(180 - ((row * 1.0)/side) * 360)
        g_row = (abs(90 - lat)/180)*side
        fraction = g_row-math.floor(g_row)

        # Here I optimized the code by using the numpy vector operations 
        # instead of the for loop:

        high_row = geo[math.floor(g_row), :] * (fraction)
        low_row = geo[math.ceil(g_row), :] * (1-fraction)
        merc[row, :] = high_row + low_row

    return merc
```

If I run it on my machine it takes less then a second:

```
%timeit mercator_faster(geo)
1 loops, best of 3: 727 ms per loop
```

And it looks like this (I had to rescale it, because it was too big for SO):

[image: Mercator Map]

Possibly the outer for loop might be vectorized as well, but I guess this is much harder.

Comment: Hey!  I love the idea, but the output from this function is not the same as the original function's output.

Comment: OK. I added a picture as well :)